How do I import special characters from foxpro fields into firebird in vb.net?
I have to migrate a legacy application written in Clipper 5 using DBF/CDX database (probably FoxPro 2.5). The new app will use firebird 4. The migration of the data is working correctly except for some especial characters (the language is Brazilian Portuguese). For instance:
"Praça " becomes "Pra?a". The same happens with á, â, ã and other special characters etc.
The overall approach is:
Dim conn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=vfpoledb;Extended Properties=""text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited;'CharacterSet=65001'"";Data Source=<my data source>")
        Dim cmdString As String = "select p.*, c.* from tb11 as p inner join tb12 as c on p.pjcodipess=c.cgcodipeem"
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(cmdString, conn)

        Dim adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
        Dim table As New DataTable()

        adapter.Fill(table)
        For Each dr As DataRow In table.Rows
            <new database field>.Value = dr("<old database column>")
            ....
        next  



I have tried some character sets (don't know all the possible options), and also the vb.net Enconding class to try to get it right. Nothing has worked so far.
All of this to avoid writing a procedure to go through each field of each table and converting data manually.
Thanks for your help.

Can you retrieve it from source and display it correctly? It's important to establish whether the issue is with retrieving the data or saving it.

Did you try code page 437 instead of 65001? Or maybe code page 860 which is intended for Portuguese.

Also, is 'CharacterSet=...' definitely the right way? Maybe there is another way: this answer uses CODEPAGE=... but not in the extended properties.

Ah, this article: Using Unicode in Visual FoxPro Web and Desktop Applications leads me to think that trying 1252 could be fruitful.

In the FoxPro database the value is "Kosvalença Comercial de Valença Ltda." It is retrieved as "Kosvalen‡a Comercial de Valen‡a Ltda. " So it is saved like that in the new database.

Tried the suggestions, but none has worked so far. Thanks. And unfortunately, the old DB is not VFP,  but FoxPro 2.5, which means it is a DOS apllication  using DOS code pages.

@CMorgado You just need to to find out which code page shows ç as ‡ and use the appropriate code page number to read the data. There are tables showing which value represents which glyph, and of course you have more interest in finding them than I do ;)
